# How to get groupby total and then calculate percentage of a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd be grateful for some help as no amount of googling or playing with .agg is helping me solve this problem.
I have a dataframe with election results. I have grouped by Municipality and PartyName to get a total vote for each party in a municipality and it looks like this snippet after I have reset the index:

```
         Municipality                           PartyName  TotalValidVotes
0  BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN CHRISTIAN DEMOCRATIC PARTY             2519
1  BUF - Buffalo City        AFRICAN INDEPENDENT CONGRESS            15600
2  BUF - Buffalo City           AFRICAN NATIONAL CONGRESS           268052
3  BUF - Buffalo City              CONGRESS OF THE PEOPLE             3913
4  BUF - Buffalo City                 DEMOCRATIC ALLIANCE           106790
```

I am now wanting to calculate each party's percentage of the total **for a Municipality** and cannot figure out how to generate the sum of the vote per municipality so I can do the percentage calculate.
It strikes me that this should be easy to do in pandas but I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though a bit late.  You can also look at my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler and yet more efficient version:

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) on `'sum'` to get the sum of the group. Then, you can divide the column `TotalValidVotes` with this sum and multiply by 100 to get the percentages.

```
df['TotalValidVotes_Pct'] = (df['TotalValidVotes'] / df.groupby('Municipality')['TotalValidVotes'].transform('sum')) * 100
```

Note that this version **use only vectorized operation and should run faster**.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

         Municipality                           PartyName  TotalValidVotes  TotalValidVotes_Pct
0  BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN CHRISTIAN DEMOCRATIC PARTY             2519             0.634710
1  BUF - Buffalo City        AFRICAN INDEPENDENT CONGRESS            15600             3.930719
2  BUF - Buffalo City           AFRICAN NATIONAL CONGRESS           268052            67.540832
3  BUF - Buffalo City              CONGRESS OF THE PEOPLE             3913             0.985955
4  BUF - Buffalo City                 DEMOCRATIC ALLIANCE           106790            26.907784
```

Comment: I like this solution too. Very elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to groupby the two vars (`Municipality` and `PartyName`) first, then groupby the first index (`level=0`) of the resultant aggregated DataFrame, then calculate the percentage on each group (`.apply(...)`).

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """Municipality    PartyName   TotalValidVotes
BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN CHRISTIAN DEMOCRATIC PARTY  2519
BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN INDEPENDENT CONGRESS    15600
BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN NATIONAL CONGRESS   268052
BUF - Buffalo City  CONGRESS OF THE PEOPLE  3913
BUF - Buffalo City  DEMOCRATIC ALLIANCE  106790
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df = (
    df.groupby(["Municipality", "PartyName"])
    .agg({"TotalValidVotes": "sum"})
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda g: 100 * g / g.sum())
    .reset_index()
)
```

Which produces:

```
         Municipality                           PartyName  TotalValidVotes
0  BUF - Buffalo City  AFRICAN CHRISTIAN DEMOCRATIC PARTY         0.634710
1  BUF - Buffalo City        AFRICAN INDEPENDENT CONGRESS         3.930719
2  BUF - Buffalo City           AFRICAN NATIONAL CONGRESS        67.540832
3  BUF - Buffalo City              CONGRESS OF THE PEOPLE         0.985955
4  BUF - Buffalo City                 DEMOCRATIC ALLIANCE        26.907784
```

This snippet should work without the need to make an intermediate DataFrame.

Comment: Wonderful. Works perfectly. I would never have solved this on my own. Thanks a million.